# Chern number for curves in a toric variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry

Suppose $X$ is a non-singular toric variety that is the closure of the complex torus $X^\circ \simeq T_{\mathbb C}$. Let $Y_1,\dots, Y_N$ be the closures of codimension one $T_{\mathbb C}$-orbits, so that $X$ is the union $X^\circ \cup Y_1 \cup \dots \cup Y_N$.

Let $u: \mathbb P^1 \to X$ be a holomorphic curve that intersects $X^\circ$, and therefore intersects each of the divisors $Y_1,\dots,Y_N$ at isolated points.
I would like to see a proof of the fact that the first Chern number $c_1(u^*TX)$ is the sum of the intersection numbers of $u$ with the divisors $Y_1,\dots,Y_N$.

Comment: The divisor $\sum Y_i$ is an anticanonical divisor of $X$. This is a standard fact about toric varieties, see e.g. Fulton *Introduction to Toric Varieties*, 4.3.